# Storing data feed as variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new to Javascript,JQuery, and JSON and i was wondering if it was possible to store a feed of data from say an RSS feed as a variable.

For example i have this code which  recieves a feed from youtube and parses through it to get the video Ids. after each pass i would like it to store the data to be stored in a different variable.

the code is as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 getYouTubeAllInfo();
 });    

function getYouTubeAllInfo() {
       $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/SkyDoesMinecraft/uploads?orderby=updated&alt=json-in-script&callback=?&start-index=1&max-results=15', 
   function(data){
       $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item){
           var id = item['id']['$t'];
           id = id.replace("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/videos/","");
       });
   }); 
   }
```

you can view a live version here: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xemgz/14/) there is an append to a div to show you what it does.

but what i need it to do is save one iteration to one variable and the next to another. any suggestions?

Comment: You already asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916128/jquery-storing-data-feed-as-an-array. Nobody's going to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store it as an array:

```
var feedIds = [];
function getYouTubeAllInfo() {
   $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/SkyDoesMinecraft/uploads?orderby=updated&alt=json-in-script&callback=?&start-index=1&max-results=15', 
       function(data){
           $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item){
               var id = item['id']['$t'];
               id = id.replace("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/videos/","");
               feedIds.push(item['id']);
           });
           console.log(feedIds);
   }); 
}
```

Comment: You know that `console.log(feedIds);` is useless there? It somehow suggests that it will show the elements that were added to the array, which won't be the case.

Comment: this seems to kind of do the trick, but i think that it might be pushing the values from '$t' into the array as well. i only need the info from the item['id'] to get pushed, when i remove the second part of the array it just explodes. any suggestions?

Comment: can i have it push to the array at a specific iteration?